# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de ver cuando selecciono el correo y contraseña me debe devolver todos los datos del usuario y estoy tratando de cuando me devuelva el ID 1 que seria el usuario administrador me dirija a la pagina del administrador, si no es así a la pagina del usuario normal pero me da un error que dice:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Evaluación3\V-Login.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Evaluación3\V-Login.php(30): mysqli_stmt->fetch(3) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Evaluación3\V-Login.php on line 30"

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
/***** Iniciar variable de sesión ****/

session_start();

$Correo=$_POST['Correo'];
$Contraseña=$_POST['Contraseña'];

$nombre_servidor = "127.0.0.1";
$nombre_usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$nombre_bd = "blizzard";

/***** Crear Conexion ****/
$Conexion = mysqli_connect ($nombre_servidor, $nombre_usuario, $password, $nombre_bd);


/***** revisar Conexion ****/
if (!$Conexion) {
    die("La conexión falló: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }


/***** Consultar si el usuario existe ****/

$stmt = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios where Correo = ? and Contraseña = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $Correo, $Contraseña);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

   
/***** Usuario existe, enviar a pagina principal ****/
if ($row == true) {

    $_SESSION['Correo'] = $Correo;  /***** Crear variable de session ****/

    $ID = $row[0];
    if($ID ==1){
        header(location:"M-Admi");
    }else{
        header(location:"index.php");
    }

 
 
}

/***** Usuario no existe, devolverlo al Login mostrando una ventana emergente ****/   
else{
    echo "<script>
      alert('Credenciales incorrectas');
      window.location.href = 'Login.html';
    </script>";
}

/***** Cerrar conexion y sentencia preparada ****/
$stmt->close();
$Conexion->close();

?>
```

Comment: Soy muy novato :(, muchas gracias por ese comentario, pero como podria hacerlo usando select norma "sql"??

Comment: pero entonces como podria saber si el ID el igual a 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error *`Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given`* es bastante claro. **El método `fetch` de `mysqli` NO necesita parámetros**, y tú le estás pasando uno que además es un parámetro propio de PDO.

Te aconsejo que leas siempre la documentación de los métodos que quieres usar, allí se explica con claridad cómo usarlos y te recomiendan prácticas que deberías observar al escribir el código. Para `fetch()` [puedes consultar aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Allí se explica que debes **vincular a variables los resultados que quieres obtener de una consulta preparada**. Para no hacerlo demasiado difícil, recomiendo que escribas un `SELECT` explícito con aquellas columnas que quieras recuperar y uses variables para cada una de ellas. Además es una buena práctica usar `SELECT` explícitos.

Según dices, lo que interesa aquí es el `ID`, asumo que esa columna se llama `ID`, si no es así lo cambias. Entonces el código quedaría así:

```
/***** Consultar si el usuario existe ****/

$stmt = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT ID FROM usuarios where Correo = ? and Contraseña = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $Correo, $Contraseña);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id);
$row = $stmt->fetch();

#Sólo para depurar
var_dump($id);

//Resto del código
```

Lo que ha ocurrido aquí es que hemos escrito un select explícito: `SELECT ID FROM ...` asignando a la variable `$id` el resultado de la consulta preparada. Si fueran más columnas en el `SELECT` deberías poner más variables en `bind_result` y luego usar esa variables. Está muy claramente explicado en la documentación (enlace de más arriba), así como en las [explicaciones del método `bind_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

Haciendo eso el problema debería desaparecer. Si persiste, dilo en comentarios indicando el nuevo problema o error.

Comment: Una consulta ¿como puedo contactarme con usted?

Comment: @DavidPhillipsTorres por aquí mismo, vía preguntas/respuestas y comentarios en las mismas o vía Twitter (está en mi perfil).

Comment: es que necesito ayuda con una tarea